# I am done with HTML and CSS. Now, what Web Development tools should I start with?

Tags: html, css, web-development, website-design, html5

I am done with HTML and CSS. Now, what Web Development tools should I start with?

Should I start with *Adobe CS3*, *Adobe CS4* or *Adobe CS5*

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Tools to do what? How are you 'done' with html/css? CS3/4/5 all do a perfectly good job of whatever applications your referring to - there isn't a *massive* amount of difference.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are getting into web development.

I suggest you looking into [Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/). A really good start to have a solid template and setup for both HTML5, CSS and eventually your JavaScript.

As for tools/IDE, Adobe tools are great, but sometimes overwhelming. There are many other free alternatives out there, line Notepad++ for coding and paint.net for image editing. Whatever software you decide to use, just stick with it and learn to use it well.

You may want to look for writing the code yourself, not using any WYSIWYG functionality EVER.

One great thing to start coding and practicing is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).